# Google Webmaster Tools api sites.add Issue

Tags: google-api, google-search-console

Currently i am using google webmaster API in my project, initially the API was working fine and did the following tasks:

Adding a site to google webmaster tools account.
Verify the site using FILE method.
Adding site map to the site.

Unfortunately in the past week that API is not working, the first step of adding a site under the webmaster account is not working. However the later two steps are working fine as manually i added the site to webmaster account and run the API that verified the site and added a site map as well.
I tried to debug the API and get the response code. The response code was 204 but still the site could not be added to webmaster account.

The API that i am using is under the following link as recommended by google and its V3.
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Webmasters.php

Now i am in a deadlock situation as i am getting the correct response code and the task is not being accomplished bearing in mind that it was working 2 weeks before.

Comment: Anyone able to comment???